# Boost Graph Library: Prim's algorithm with negative edge weights

Tags: c++, boost-graph, prims-algorithm

I am currently working with the BGL using

```
    prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g, parent.data());
```

However, my Graph does contain edges with negative weights. This results in following Error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::negative_edge>'
what():  The graph may not contain an edge with negative weight.
```

This seems kind of strange to me since Prim's algorithm works perfectly fine with negative edge weights. How come that this is still a problem for BGL?
Also, what would be the easiest way to fix this problem? Do I have to add a constant on all edge's weight to make them all positive or is this avoidable?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could add the absolute value of the minimum edge to all edges and after the prim's function call, subtract the same from all edges.

Comment: @srt1104 yes that works, but as mentioned I'd like to avoid that

Comment: Have you compated with https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/graph/doc/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.html

Comment: @sehe No I have not since Kruskal's implementation does not provide that the output is stored as a predecessor map (correct me if I am wrong) which became quite necessary. Even if that would work with negative weights, I think transforming the output of Kruskal's takes just as much effort as adding a constant on all weights and subtracting it again afterwards

Comment: @Manuel.math Kruskal outputs a sequence of edges in the MST. That's basically all the predecessors (source of each edge). Perhaps you're implying that you like the convenience of already writing it to random-access container indexed by vertex id. I submiet that this ONLY applies when you have `vecS` as the vertex container selector, which I did not assume. Yes, that might be an advantage. (I'm not actually aware of whether Kruskal supports negative weights)